# Do not understand method in interface

Tags: java, interface, default

I have following interface:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target(value={ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Transactional {

    public Class[] rollbackon() default {};

}
```

What is the meaning of `default {}` ? I know that  in Java 8 there is the possibility  to implement concrete methods in interfaces. Is it something like that?

Comment: That is not an interface. It's an annotation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html

Comment: Please answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was my fault :-))):

First of all: `Transactional` is not an interface it is an annotation.

For annotations you can define attributes by method-like declarations.

And for this attributes or "methods" you can define optionally `default` values.